# Singular "Escape" in Monomial Integration

Tags: analysis, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't you integrate all power functions without a log function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45393/why-cant-you-integrate-all-power-functions-without-a-log-function)

We know that $f(r,x)=\int_{1}^xt^r dt=\frac x{1+r}+C$ if $r\neq -1$ and $=\log x+C$ if $r=-1$. 
I find this quite strange. It's a weird singularity right there, where integrating a monomial $x^r$ would "escape" to another class of equations only at $r=-1$.

1. Is there any explanation for this phenomenon?
2. What about similar singular behaviors in other such functions?

Comment: We have $e^{\lambda x}$ at $\lambda=0$.  And many relatives with a division by $0$ issue.

Comment: Consider $x^\alpha=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}(x-1)^k$. Integrating that yields $\int_1^x t^\alpha \mathrm dt=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}\frac{(x-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}$ From the series point of view, things aren't *too* strange, since $\binom{\alpha}{k}$ is nothing more than a degree-$k$ polynomial in $\alpha$...

Comment: Consider also the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind $T_k(x)=\cos(k\arccos\,x)$. There is the integration formula $\int T_k(x)\mathrm dx=\frac12\left(\frac{T_{k+1}(x)}{k+1}-\frac{T_{k-1}(x)}{k-1}\right)$, which very obviously breaks down when $k=1$; however, $T_1(x)=x$, and that function is perfectly integrable...

Comment: It only seems strange because you aren't computing $C$ (which depends on $r$). Compute $C$ and see what happens.

Comment: See also the second explanation in my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129849/linear-homogeneous-recurrence-relations-with-repeated-roots-motivation-behind-l/129855#129855 for another example of this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather broad class of examples.  Suppose $F(x)$ is a differentiable function with $F'(x) = f(x)$.  Then $\int f(\lambda x)\ dx = \lambda^{-1} F(\lambda x) + C$ for $\lambda \ne 0$.  Of course that doesn't make sense for $\lambda = 0$, where $\int f(0x)\ dx = f(0) x + C$ instead.

EDIT: At first sight your example of $\int t^r \ dt$ doesn't appear to fit this paradigm, but if you first do the change of variables $t = e^x$ it becomes $\int e^{(r+1) x}\ dx$ which does.